# Blank UIExplorer Example App

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm trying to run the example react-native apps in iOS simulator, but when I followed the instructions, I end up with a blank page. No errors, just a blank white screen. I'm confused that there is no index.ios.js and am assuming this is where the problem resides. There are dozens of specific js files broken out to their respective roles, but what file tells the app which js file to pull from when? I would expect it to be the index file, but maybe I'm supposed to set another file as index?

Answer (score 0):

When you open your AppDelegate.m file of your target project under xcode, the value of the jsCodeLocation should give you an idea/hint of how the app is started.